# Rotation angle is clockwise or counterclockwise?

Tags: qgis, autocad

Does QGIS use clockwise or counterclockwise angle? 
In Esri Desktop, I can change rotation style from Geographic to Arithmetic.

[image]

In QGIS, is there any way to change the Rotation Style to make it use counterclockwise angles?

Comment: Angles are used in many places in QGIS and there are possibly several conventions used. For example North=0 increasing anticlockwise, which is the usual geographic convention, or East=0 increasing clockwise which is the mathematical convention. Which bit of QGIS are you concerned with?

Comment: Why is this question tagged `autocad`?